# C# Deploying MS Access reference

Tags: c#, ms-access

I wanted to know about deploying a referenced COM object in C# Express.

I have added the MS Access object, which is used in one of my functions.  However. when I build an installation package using the "Publish" tool within Express - it doesn't appear to add it to the package.

This has caused a problem on my test-bed PC, which has nothing on it except Windows.  The app works fine until it gets to the point of needing the Access reference/object.  At which point it throws up an exception error.

If this is a licencing issue - that's fine (and understandable), but I just need a bit of info on the subject.

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internal .Net Assemblies are not copied to the output directory unless you tell Visual Studio to do so. Just go to the referenced assembly and set the  "copy local" option to "true".

A more convenient way would be to manually include the file in the project (seach for it on you dev pc) and do a project reference to the copied file (sounds strange but this way the GAC registration process should not be needed on the test machine)

Another way is of course as stated to install the complete interop package as stated above.

This doesn`t cover any license issues since it is not well defined by Microsoft.. there are 2 general opinions:

- interop assemblies only create the possibility to "talk" to office so it is free to use them .. but why execute it on a system that has no office?
- interop assemblies have the same EULA as Office so can only be used when installing Office

No clear statement from Microsoft, I think this is a common Microsoft tactic...

Answer (score 1):

Installing the [Office Primary Interop Assemblies](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=3508) on the target machine should work, although I can't advise on the licensing aspect.

Either way, Access or the PIA's need to be there.